# How to compile a Linux kernel with certificate / public key builtin?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, certificates

I'd like to compile Linux Kernel 4.1.3 with a Public Key or self signed certificate built into the kernel.

Is there a kernel option where I can specify the certificate/public key  I want to add to the kernel at compile time?

The goal is to provide the IMA module with a public key to verify/appraise file signatures.